# Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe' ! astype function between int and float

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I want to plot x,y with PCA but i get this problem of casting, despite my list is  int  and (y,x)  are float  :

```
    csv = np.genfromtxt ('main_contentieux_IPLSCRS_dataset.csv', 
    delimiter=";")
    y = csv[:,0]
    x = csv[:,1:]


    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
    plt.clf()
    ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)

    plt.cla()
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=4)
    pca.fit(x)
    X_fits = pca.transform(x)
    for name, label in [('Aixe en provance', 0), ('Paris', 1), 
      ('Versailles', 2)]:
       ax.text3D(X_fits[y == label, 0].mean(),X_fits[y == label, 
       1].mean()+1.5,X_fits[y == label, 
       2].mean(),name,horizontalalignment='center',bbox=dict(alpha=.8, 
       edgecolor='w', facecolor='w'))

   # Reorder the labels to have colors matching the cluster results

   y = np.choose(y,[0,2,1]).astype(np.float)
```

The error is in the casting  :

```
     y = np.choose(y,[0,2,1]).astype(np.float)

     y is : <class 'numpy.float64'>  and my list [0,2,1] contain int

     ** x and y contains float values,so the problem is in  the casting  when i  try to use (astype) function !  I want to fix it , **
```

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @cheersmate  y is  :  [0. 2. 2. ... 1. 1. 1.]   and my list is [0,2,1] so when i cast (  y = np.choose(y,[0,2,1]).astype(np.float))  i  get  this  error   :  TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the relevant information. But what you wrote is still far from an mcve. Please [read the information in the help docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.choose` expects an `int` array as first argument, but you seem to be passing floats. You can cast the first argument to mitigate this:

```
y = np.choose(y.astype(int), [0,2,1]).astype(float)
```